# How can I control execution of Jmeter when multiple users login?

Tags: multithreading, loops, jmeter, wiki, multi-user

I have recorded a script using an existing user for wiki page
Recorded actions;

- Login
- Create a Page
- Edit a Page
- Logout

I have separated above actions using transaction controller elements.
Then I have added list of users (100 users) using CSV data set config element to test plan.

Now users (100 users) are login to system and then all the users creates wiki page at once, after creation process all the users edits the page and after end of edit actions all the users logout from the system.

But i want to change above scenario into below:

User 1: Login --> Create a Page --> Edit a page --> Logout

User 2: Login --> Create a Page --> Edit a page --> Logout

User 3: Login --> Create a Page --> Edit a page --> Logout

.

.

User 100: Login --> Create a Page --> Edit a page --> Logout

And I want to do above processes at the same time (simultaneously).

Current Process:

- Process 1: All users are login to system, Create pages at the same time
- Process 2: After creation process all users edit pages then logout.

How can i do this? Appreciate if someone could give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly if you want those actions go simultaneously then you should just put them in one controller or even straight in the thread group and raise the number of threads to 100, so they will have possibility to start at once in 1 second (Ramp-up period) and then each will go with creation-edit-logout workflow in their own pace. I'll check it, but I'm pretty sure it worked like this for me when I was working with 200 users and running a bit longer scenario than yours exactly the way as described.